# Dataframe sort_values on multiple columns with string format dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe and I want to sort by two columns - first by **id** and those then need to be sorted in **date** order, both in ascending order, with the earliest date first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [9733, 9733, 9733, 9733, 9733, 9733, 9733, 9733, 2949, 2949, 2949, 2949, 2949, 2949, 2949, 9765, 9765, 9765, 9765, 9765, 9765],
        "date": ["01/05/2008", "01/06/1968", "01/11/2010", "01/12/2016", "09/03/2011", "09/05/1975", "28/04/2011", "29/01/2005", "08/07/1974", "09/03/2021", "10/03/2021", "18/09/1986", "20/07/2021", "23/09/2017", "26/06/2020", "01/04/1963", "01/08/2012", "02/08/2012", "25/06/2021", "30/11/2020", "31/03/1986",],
        "status": ["S", "A", "P", "C", "S", "D", "P", "P", "A", "P", "S", "D", "P", "P", "S", "A", "S", "P", "P", "S", "P"],
    }
)
```

First, I change the **date** column to datetime and apply the dd/mm/yyyy format:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Then, I tried using the sort_values function:

```
df.sort_values(by=['id','date'], ascending=[True,True], inplace=True)
```

I'm getting the **id** column sorted in ascending order. However, the **date** column isn't in ascending order and this is where I can't work out where I'm going wrong:

[image]

Ultimately, I want the dataframe sorted by the earliest P **status** only (I want A status and D status separately which I figure I use .filter to get that, each will be output to an Excel file in separate worksheets), but I'm stuck with the ordering of the **id** and **dates**.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you only want to sort dataframe where only P in the column ```status``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert it to a string, the date will be sorted based on alphabetic/lexicographic order. so your data *is* sorted correctly, given the fact that you specify a string with `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

If you don't want it sorted in that order, then sort the data first, then convert it to a string:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values(by=['id','date'], ascending=[True,True], inplace=True)
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Alternatively, to numerically sort the string-formatted dates, you can provide a custom `key` argument to [`pd.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```py
In [8]: df.sort_values(
   ...:     by=['id','date'],
   ...:     ascending=[True,True],
   ...:     inplace=True,
   ...:     key=lambda col: (
   ...:         pd.to_datetime(col, format="%d/%m/%Y")
   ...:         if col.name == "date"
   ...:         else col
   ...:     ),
   ...: )

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
      id        date status
8   2949  08/07/1974      A
11  2949  18/09/1986      D
13  2949  23/09/2017      P
14  2949  26/06/2020      S
9   2949  09/03/2021      P
10  2949  10/03/2021      S
12  2949  20/07/2021      P
1   9733  01/06/1968      A
5   9733  09/05/1975      D
7   9733  29/01/2005      P
0   9733  01/05/2008      S
2   9733  01/11/2010      P
4   9733  09/03/2011      S
6   9733  28/04/2011      P
3   9733  01/12/2016      C
15  9765  01/04/1963      A
20  9765  31/03/1986      P
16  9765  01/08/2012      S
17  9765  02/08/2012      P
19  9765  30/11/2020      S
18  9765  25/06/2021      P
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Michael! Never thought about the key parameter. Learned a lot from your answer and I appreciate it very much. I have learned about Pandas on some courses (mostly Udemy) but I always seem to struggle in 'real world' issues. Everything I searched on Google about sort_values mentioned the ascending part, but none mentioned the key parameter! Is there some course you can recommend so that I can become as awesome as someone like you? Seems like there are some great developers on Stackoverflow and it'd be good to know where to tap into to get to your level of Pandas knowledge :)

Comment: Wow thanks! Glad it helped. Hanging out here is a good strategy, as is always assuming there is a right way to do things and that if you have an issue, someone else has probably already solved it and you just need to find it. That holds true 99.9% of the time for me, and leads to some pretty great finds in the docs and on this site. You’ll get there!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well you question, you need to sort only when the column status has value P:

```
#1 convert the column date to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#2 split the dataframe to 2 dataframes
df1 = df.loc[df['status'].eq('P')].sort_values(by=['id','date'], ascending=[True,True])
df2 = df.loc[df['status'].ne('P')]

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True) #this is your new df
```

Comment: based on "Ultimately ..., but I'm stuck with the ordering of the id and dates", to me it seems the question focuses on sorting dates, which in the picture are numerically (but not alphabetically) out of order. Filtering based on P is a next step which the OP knows how to deal with.